# Why declaration of a field in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass in not recommended?

Tags: java

Why declaration of a field in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass in not recommended? It is stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). What this *hiding* can lead to? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are two issues here:

- The confusion of one field hiding another
- The confusion of having two pieces of state which presumably mean very similar things

The first point is easily alleviated by simply keeping fields private, which is generally a good idea anyway. However, the second point is arguably more important. If you've got two fields both called `name` (for example) in the same object, even if no single piece of code is aware of both fields, that suggests that *either* there are genuinely two kinds of name within that object, in which case it would be helpful for at least one of the field names to be more specific, *or* you've got two fields representing the same piece of state, which is very fragile, as well as inefficient. (It's all too easy to change one but not the other, for example.)